# Is plotting an image on a map with matplotlib possible?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using basemap it's easy to plot a set of coordinates, like so:

```
x, y = m(lons, lats)    
m.plot(x, y, 'go')
```

but would it be possible to use an image instead of the green circle ('go')? I didn't find a direct way of doing this from the documentation.

So, let's clarify this a bit: I'm using a map generated with basemap as a background and would like to plot some .png images on top of it instead of the regular plain markers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to draw `.png` images then you should try http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow

You might also be interested in the Matplotlib Basemap toolkit. http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/basemap/doc/html/

Comment: I'm trying to use a .png image instead of a plain marker, and yes, I'm doing this on a Basemap-generated map.

Answer (score 1):

For your reference, I answered a similar question to this the other day: [Python Matplotlib Basemap overlay small image on map plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487797/python-matplotlib-basemap-overlay-small-image-on-map-plot/11495585#11495585)