# Error setting data for matplotlib annotation box for use in animation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib-basemap

I am using `matplotlib.animation` to animate changes in position of multiple points over time on `matplotlib.Basemap` map.

I have got it working for me for basic points, but I have been trying to plot the points as images, let's say a [image]   ([like was explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487797/python-matplotlib-basemap-overlay-small-image-on-map-plot)) and include a legend which displays the day count for each day being plotted.

When I attempt to plot the points as images, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'AnnotationBbox' object has no attribute 'set_data'
```

How does one set the data for such an object?

Answer (score 1):

After creating the annotation object:

```
image = np.array(Image.open(img_filename))
im = OffsetImage(image, zoom=1)
ab = AnnotationBbox(im, (x, y), xycoords='data', frameon=False)
```

I ran a `dir(ab)` to find what attributes the object had. It appears the correct attribute to set the position data for an annotation box is `xytext`, which can be set by doing the following:

```
ab.xytext = (new_x, new_y)
```

I am attempting to do this with a list of images, so now I am receiving the error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'axes'` when returning the list of annotation boxes from `init()` and `animate(i)`, which I will follow up on in another question.